# User image to Discord Embed

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, embed

I want the image that a user sends to be fetched and put into an embed that the bot will then send. As the image must be a url and the person sends an image, I don't know how I can transform this image into a url.
When doing the command, the embed send but without the image. This is what i've tried but it didn't work :

```
const plotEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed() 
                        .setTitle(`Purchase of the plot n°${plotId}`)
                        .setColor("GREEN")
                        .setDescription(`Purchase of plot ${plotId} for ${days} days.`)
                        .setImage(message.attachments.first.url)
                        .setTimestamp()
message.channel.send({ embeds: [pEmbed]})
```

If someone could get me an advice on what I should try  because I don't really know...
Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `message.attachments` gives a collection, so you can use the `.map()` command to get the urls. All you have to do is change your code to:

```js
const attachmentURL = message.attachments.map(attachment => attachment.url)
const plotEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle(`Purchase of the plot n°${plotId}`)
  .setColor("GREEN")
  .setDescription(`Purchase of plot ${plotId} for ${days} days.`)
  .setImage(attachmentURL[0])
  .setTimestamp()
message.channel.send({
  embeds: [pEmbed]
})
```

This might just be the fact that pEmbed was declared before your code snippet but just wanted to tell that you are sending an embed called `pEmbed` while the embed in your current code snippet is in a variable called `plotEmbed`, so you might want to change that.

Edit:

Just found another way which is the simpler one. You just made a mistake calling `message.attachments.first`. It should actually be `message.attachments.first().url` because `first()` is actually a function. So this should also work exactly like the first method I posted

Comment: These two methods work well, thank you so much. And yeah, my bad on naming my embed. Thanks again!